# In IDA, i want to get symbol by using IDAPython

Tags: ida, c++, idapython

I'm currently reversing some C++ Binary (macOS Kernel Extension).
But, there are a lot of vtable functions, so i want to make some vtable structures by using IDAPython.

I know how to make structure itself, but i don't know how to get symbol in following case.

```
UNDEF:0000000000003E60 ; IORegistryEntry::compareName(OSString *, OSString **)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E60                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11compareNameEP8OSStringPS1_:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E60                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002410↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E60                                         ; __const:0000000000002F40↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E68 ; IORegistryEntry::getLocation(IORegistryPlane const*)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E68                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getLocationEPK15IORegistryPlane:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E68                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002428↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E68                                         ; __const:0000000000002F58↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E70 ; IORegistryEntry::getProperty(OSString const*)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E70                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getPropertyEPK8OSString:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E70                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002320↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E70                                         ; __const:0000000000002E50↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E78 ; IORegistryEntry::getProperty(OSString const*, IORegistryPlane const*, unsigned int)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E78                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getPropertyEPK8OSStringPK15IORegistryPlanej:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E78                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002338↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E78                                         ; __const:0000000000002E68↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E80 ; IORegistryEntry::getProperty(OSSymbol const*)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E80                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getPropertyEPK8OSSymbol:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E80                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002318↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E80                                         ; __const:0000000000002E48↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E88 ; IORegistryEntry::getProperty(OSSymbol const*, IORegistryPlane const*, unsigned int)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E88                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getPropertyEPK8OSSymbolPK15IORegistryPlanej:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E88                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002330↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E88                                         ; __const:0000000000002E60↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E90 ; IORegistryEntry::getProperty(char const*)const
UNDEF:0000000000003E90                 extrn __ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getPropertyEPKc:qword
UNDEF:0000000000003E90                                         ; DATA XREF: __const:0000000000002328↑o
UNDEF:0000000000003E90                                         ; __const:0000000000002E58↑o

...
```

I want to get above symbol name.
I tried to use idc.GetFunctionName and idautils.Functions(), i can't get symbol name fully. Result is below.

```
Python>import idautils
Python>for func in idautils.Functions():
Python>  print(hex(func), idc.GetFunctionName(func))

...

('0x3950L', '__ZN15OSMetaClassBase12safeMetaCastEPKS_PK11OSMetaClass')
('0x3a08L', '__ZN8OSObjectdlEPvm')
('0x3a10L', '__ZN8OSObjectnwEm')
('0x3e00L', '__ZN9IOServiceC2EPK11OSMetaClass')
('0x3e08L', '__ZN9IOServiceD2Ev')
('0x3e38L', '__ZNK11OSMetaClass19instanceConstructedEv')
('0x3fb0L', '__ZNK9IOService10isInactiveEv')
```

Is there some good way to get symbols?

Answer (score 4):

These names are mangled. You need to demangle it back.

1 - Read something about [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) in order to understand why clear `IORegistryEntry::getProperty(OSString const*)const` is converted to `__ZNK15IORegistryEntry11getPropertyEPK8OSString` .

2 - Use demangling in IDA python ([idc.demangle_name](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#demangle_name) or [ida_name.demangle_name](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_name-module.html#demangle_name)).

3 - If something goes wrong, you can go to [online demangler](https://demangler.com/).

It converts your

> ('0x3950L', '__ZN15OSMetaClassBase12safeMetaCastEPKS_PK11OSMetaClass')
>   ('0x3a08L', '__ZN8OSObjectdlEPvm') ('0x3a10L', '__ZN8OSObjectnwEm')
>   ('0x3e00L', '__ZN9IOServiceC2EPK11OSMetaClass') ('0x3e08L',
>   '__ZN9IOServiceD2Ev') ('0x3e38L',
>   '__ZNK11OSMetaClass19instanceConstructedEv') ('0x3fb0L',
>   '__ZNK9IOService10isInactiveEv')

to

```
('0x3950L', '_OSMetaClassBase::safeMetaCast(OSMetaClassBase const*, OSMetaClass const*)')
('0x3a08L', '_OSObject::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)')
('0x3a10L', '_OSObject::operator new(unsigned long)')
('0x3e00L', '_IOService::IOService(OSMetaClass const*)')
('0x3e08L', '_IOService::~IOService()')
('0x3e38L', '_OSMetaClass::instanceConstructed() const')
('0x3fb0L', '_IOService::isInactive() const')
```